# Read only field does not postback from Gridview

Tags: vb.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I have a Gridview with a SQL data source attached. The smart tag set up was used to create and handle Select and Updates. When I edit Gridview columns to make 2 date fields Read Only, on the Update Event they are cleared, deleted, blanked out in the DB table.

Here is the kicker, when the column is NOT Read Only, the date is correctly posted back to the DB table.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="dateRegisteredUTC" HeaderText="dateRegisteredUTC" SortExpression="dateRegisteredUTC" />
```

No template fields, all are bound.

Comment: I don't have a lot of information from your problem but it might be related to this ["... control with the ReadOnly property set to true is sent to the server when a postback occurs, but the server does no processing... "](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.readonly(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: hmm, let me look at that. I am not sure it applies. ViewState is enabled so that value should still be there.

Comment: @the_lotus If you post your comment as an answer I will except it. It was an indirect solution to my issue which worked, so Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a lot of information from your problem but it might be related to this ["... control with the ReadOnly property set to true is sent to the server when a postback occurs, but the server does no processing... "](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.readonly(v=vs.110).aspx). What this mean is that when a control is readonly, chances are .NET isn't updating the value on a postback.